# Using ghostscript gswin64c / gswin32c with github actions

Tags: windows, github, ghostscript, github-actions

I'm trying to use gswin64c (gswin32c would be OK as well, but with the small script below it gives the same problems) with GitHub Actions, but after installation of the package it still cannot find the gswin64c executable
The used workflow:

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: ${{ matrix.config.name }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
        - {
            name: "Windows Latest MSVC Debug",
            os: windows-latest,
            build_type: "Debug", cc: "cl", cxx: "cl",
            build_gen: "NMake Makefiles"
          }
    steps:
    - name: Install Ghostscript (Windows)
      run:
        choco install ghostscript
      if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-latest'

    - name: Check tool versions (Windows)
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "=== ghostscript 64 bit ===";
        gswin64c --version;
      if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-latest'
```

I'm getting the error:

```
 === ghostscript 64 bit ===
D:\a\_temp\2690ee6c-4c94-4de6-9dac-3f11a4aee19e.sh: line 19: gswin64c: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

- What am I doing wrong ?
- alternative installation can be considered as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding is the second the step:

```
    - name: Setting Ghostscript paths (Windows)
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "C:/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.53.3/bin/" >> $GITHUB_PATH
        echo "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.53.3/bin/" >> $GITHUB_PATH
        export PATH="/c/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.53.3/bin/:$PATH"
        export PATH="/c/Program Files/gs/gs9.53.3/bin/:$PATH"
      if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-latest'
```

makes gswin64c available.